# Radio Button failed sometimes to get value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$("#btn").on("click",()=>{
const rdValue = $("#frm").serialize();
       var _IsOccupant = false;
       if ($("input[name='IsOccupant']:checked").val() == 1)
           _IsOccupant = true;
                
  alert(rdValue + " " + _IsOccupant);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="frm">
<label>True</label>
     <input type="radio" id="rbOwner" value="1" name="IsOccupant" required="" />

<label>False</label>
<input type="radio" id="rbOccupant" value="2" name="IsOccupant" required="" />
     
</form>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

I am wondering why sometime my code upon publish failed to determine the checkbox value`(Checked checkbox)`. But when I manually debug it it returns the correct value. Does anyone knows the reason for this?.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code goes here
    $("#btn").on("click",()=>{
    const rdValue = $("#frm").serialize();
    var _IsOccupant = false;
    if ($("input[name='IsOccupant']:checked").val() == 1)
       _IsOccupant = true;
            
    alert(rdValue + " " + _IsOccupant);
    });
})
```

This will ensure your JavaScript executes only when the document is fully loaded.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the doc.ready. But It is wrap inside the doc ready.

Answer (score 0):

To take the values from an input tag kind is necessary to use the .value function instead of .val

Is something similar to this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  
<head> 
    <title> 
        Get value of selected 
        radio button 
    </title> 
</head> 
  
<body> 
    <p> 
        Select a radio button and click on Submit. 
    </p> 
      
    Gender: 
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male 
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female 
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Others">Others 
      
    <br> 
      
    <button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()"> 
        Submit 
    </button> 
      
    <br> 
      
    <div id="result"></div> 
      
    <script> 
        function displayRadioValue() { 
            var ele = document.getElementsByName('gender'); 
              
            for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) { 
                if(ele[i].checked) 
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML
                        = "Gender: "+ele[i].value; 
            } 
        } 
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male 
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female 
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Others">Others 
      
    <br> 
      
    <button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()"> 
        Submit 
    </button> 
      
    <br> 
      
    <div id="result"></div>
```